# Web application to store and modify InDesign assets

Tags: web-apps, pdf, digital-asset-management

We're looking to buy a Web application that can manage InDesign files with variables and render high res PDFs of those files.

It will allow users to log onto their portal to see their assets, set the text to appear in the variables (i.e. date, address, etc.), and then download the print quality PDF to send to their own printer.

(If it happens to integrate with WordPress then all the better.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Alfresco can help you manage InDesign files and generate previews of them, but unfortunately it seems that it can not generate high res PDFs: http://www.ixxus.com/blog201203alfresco-and-adobe-indesign/

Answer (score 0):

[InDesign Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesignserver.html) does exactly what you describe, but it's not php, doesn't integrate with WordPress and costs 10,000s. If you're ready to sacrifice InDesign and use PDF templates instead, I'm not aware of such an application, but it can be relatively easily built using freely available tools like [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/).